# dynamic ng-model with value key in Ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<div id="id04" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content animate">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in rc.editModalRequest">
        <td> {{key}} </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" ng-model="newObj[$index]" class="editable" value="{{ value }} "/>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button class='btn waves-effect waves-light' onclick="document.getElementById('id04').style.display='none'">Close</button>
</div>
```

So this is a modal that was setup to display an object for editing purposes. I can't hard code the ng-models because there are 3 different types of objects that will be read/edited in this modal. Currently the code works perfectly if I remove the ng-model tag. It will display the object in editable inputs regardless of obj size (the 3 kinds differ).

But I am now banging my head over a way to grab the updated information from the DOM. I'm aware that you can't use value tags along with ng-model but I can't think of another way to display the data from the ng-repeat and get the data on my script.

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question, I'm feeling burned out.

Comment: If you want to change the values on the `rc.editModalRequest` object, your `ng-model` should be `rc.editModalRequest[key]`. If you want to bind to some ***new*** object, you can do exactly what you have done if you want, though you will have to initialize the array on your scope.

Comment: thank you! You were on the money, I guess I never realized you could bind an ng-model to a specific object property of a $scope object, I've always bound it to specific vars that holds the data as a primitive.